# Последняя колонка Bootstrap уходит вправо

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, float, grid

[Вот здесь](https://orange-catfish-18.localtunnel.me/services.html) колонка (блок) "Балансировка" почему-то уходит вправо, хотя у всех этих блоков стоит `float: left;`. Как сместить ее влево, где она и должна быть?

Comment: У нас принято приводить код в вопросе, минимально необходимый пример -- чтобы потом ответ и вопрос могли прочитать другие годы спустя. Вижу, что часа не прошло как вы удалили эту страницу с сайта - сейчас там 404. Вопрос нужно закрыть, да и минус проставить, чтобы в следующий раз знали, что так делать не стоит.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5263/213987)

Answer (score 1):

Весьма прозаичный ответ :

Если вы откроете разметку страницы то увидите, что блок №3 имеет высоту большую нежели высота блока №5 - если вы статично зададите `min-height: 350px` (например) - вы получите нужный результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если то же самое со статьями, где высота из-за их количества символов будет разной? Если я задам высоту принудительно, то какой-то из текстов будет обрезаться. А разделять на разные `.row` не получится в виду той специфики, что для этого надо вносить изменения в движок + компоненты, писать лишнюю логику (лишние серверные вычисления). Сколько лет работал с колонками Bootstrap, мне казалось что они специально написаны уже так, чтобы не надо было разделять по разным `.row`. И они действительно нормально работали. Взять ту же страницу `about.html`. А вот тут такой казус. Прибегать к JS?

Comment: задайте `min-height` и `max-height` - но скорее всего, полные статьи не пишут в таком стиле, обычно в карточке статьи `view more...` и тогда открывается полная статья

Comment: отредактировал под `min-height`

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение. Задать для колонок следующий псевдо-элемент:

```
&:nth-of-type(2n + 1) {
    clear: both;
}
```

Также есть решения [тут](https://cfxdesign.com/clear-bootstrap-column-floats-the-right-way/) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307766/bootstrap-columns-float-issue-divs-need-to-be-same-height) (даже с применением Flex box, но его не тестировал)